# Get text using entry.get() in tkinter and store into variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is code:

```
    import os
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
    from tkinter import *

#~~~~ FUNCTIONS~~~~

    def open_file_1():
        global file_path_1

        filename_1 = askopenfilename()
        file_path_1 = os.path.dirname(filename_1) + filename_1
        entry_1.delete(0, END)
        entry_1.insert(0, file_path_1)
        return file_path_1

    def open_file_2():
        global file_path_2

        filename_2 = askopenfilename()
        file_path_2 = os.path.dirname(filename_2) + filename_2
        entry_3.delete(0, END)
        entry_3.insert(0, file_path_2)
        return file_path_2

        def title_name_1():
            global title_1
            title_1=str(entry_4.get())
            return title_1

        def title_name_2():
            global title_2
            title_2=str(entry_5.get())
            return title_2

    def process_file(content):
        print(file_path_1)
        print(file_path_2)
        print(title_1)
        print(title_2)
```

---

```
  #~~~~~~ GUI ~~~~~~~~

root = Tk()
root.title('Test Project')
root.geometry("698x220+350+200")

mf = Frame(root)
mf.pack()


f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f1.pack(fill=X)
f3 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f3.pack(fill=X)
f4 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f4.pack(fill=X)
f5 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f5.pack(fill=X)

f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
f2.pack()



file_path_1 = StringVar
file_path_2 = StringVar
title_1 = StringVar
title_2 = StringVar


Label(f1,text="Select File 1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
Label(f3,text="Select File 2").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
Label(f4,text="Title1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
Label(f5,text="Title2").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')

entry_1 = Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=file_path_1)
entry_1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f1, text="Browse", command=open_file_1).grid(row=0, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)


entry_3 = Entry(f3, width=50, textvariable=file_path_2)
entry_3.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f3, text="Browse", command=open_file_2).grid(row=0, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

entry_4 = Entry(f4, width=50,textvariable=title_1)
entry_4.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)

entry_5 = Entry(f5, width=50,textvariable=title_2)
entry_5.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)

Button(f2, text="Submit", width=32, command=lambda: process_file(content)).grid(sticky='ew', padx=10, pady=70)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to get these 4 fields(`file_path_1`, `file_path_2`, `Title1`, `Title2`) and store them so that can be used for further manipulation.I am using Browse to select files and user will enter text for Title1 and Title2.I am new to this, so didn't have much idea.

Comment: This is too much code. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you haven't asked a question. What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating your life unnecessarily by using `StringVar()`. StringVar's are mostly useful if you attach [observer callbacks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to them...

Most of the time for Entry widgets, it is better to get their content with the `.get()` method just before using it:

```
def process_file():
    # Get Entry box content
    filename_1 = entry_1.get()
    # Do something with it
    print(filename_1)
```